# EC2 Network Error : Connection timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 micro instance of Linux and launched it, created a keypair and all the beginning stuff specified in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJRSti6DsJg

But when I connect to my instance with PUTTY terminal, it will not connect to my EC2 instance.

I have specified the correct instance Public DNS and private key which I created with the PUTTY key generator.

I get this error:

```
Network Error : Connection timeout
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you've enabled SSH access in the firewall settings of your instance?

Can you connect with PUTTY to other machines? Perhaps your local firewall is blocking SSH connections.

Also, you cannot simply use a private key you generated with PUTTY - you'll have to create one using the AWS web interface, assign it to your EC2 instance, download it to your local computer and instruct PUTTY to use this when connecting to your EC2 instance.

Comment: thanks, i able to connect now it was firewall setting issue now i fix , now i able to connect to my instance it asking loggin as i enter root as well as "ec2-user" what person enter in video but i found an error server refusing our key, please kindly tell what should be username.

Comment: If it's an AMI provided by amazon, the username should be ec2-user. Are you sure you've provided the correct key file to PUTTY?

Comment: Yes im providing correct key file, but it still giving error "Disconnected: no authentication method supported" :(

Comment: According to this (a little bit old) link http://www.freesshd.com/index.php?ctt=forum&action=view&topic=1173943044, Putty had some issues with private/public key authentication in the past. Could you test it with another SSH client?

Comment: this didn't work for me. removed firewall issue but still getting "putty fatal error, network connection timed out" even after increasing the time

Comment: It worked for me with following actions

1.Turned of McAfee firewall settings
2.Added Putty to allowed programs in windows firewall settings
3. I was using incorrect instance name, corrected it.



That's it. I can see the console with command prompt. Now I have to check how to access Ubuntu UI.

Answer (score 43):

You simply need to add an ssh rule for inbound connections to you ec2 instance in the ec2 management console.

1. Go to ec2 console
2. Click Instances on Left
3. Select your instance
4. In the Description tab, locate Security Groups and click the available group link
5. Click edit button on Inbound tab
6. Click Add Rule and select SSH for type, Port Range 22, and Source Anywhere
7. Connect with putty :)

Comment: This actually solved my problem, take this into account if you are facing the connection timed out error! Thanks.

Comment: Seems the client ip can change and as a result not match the one set in the inbound  rules. Setting the source to anywhere makes it dynamic and solves the problem. Thanks @Kevin

Answer (score 6):

Having successfully connected in the past, I got this error after shutting down my instance and starting it again.

Apparently the Public DNS changes after you shut it down and start it again, so I had to replace the DNS string in PuTTY before it could find my instance to connect with it on port 22.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I experienced the same and didn't notice that the public IP had changed, trying everything in vain.

Comment: This should be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 4):

This error may occur when you enable `ufw` and reboot your instance. First you have to add `22/tcp` before enabling `ufw`. Following is the command

`$ ufw allow 22/tcp`

If you already made the mistake. Then follow the following guide

- Start a recovery instance.
- Stop the blocked instance (DON'T TERMINATE)
- Detach the blocked instance volume.
- Attach Blocked volume to the recovery instance.
- Log to the recovery instance(Newly Launched) via ssh/putty
- Type `sudo lsblk` to display attached volumes
- Verify the name of the Blocked volume. Generally start with /dev/xvdf.
- Mount blocked volume.

```
$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt
$ cd /mnt/etc/ufw
```

- Open ufw configuration file

```
$ sudo vi ufw.conf
```

- Enable insert mode by pressing `i` in vi editor
- Update `ENABLED=yes` to `ENABLED=no`

Click`ESC` and type `:wq` to update the file.

- Verify the file contents. where update to `ENABLED=yes` -> `ENABLED=no`

```
$ sudo cat ufw.conf
```

- Remove the mounted blocked volume from recovery instance

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

- Now detach blocked install volume from recovery instance and re-attach it to the original instance as `/dev/sda1`.

Finally, Start the blocked instance. Here's you will able to access your instance. If you enable ufw again don't forget to allow 22/tcp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did the same mistake and was keep changing the security group.

Comment: how to start a recovery instance?

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to remember when using putty to connect to, add security setting to accept ssh connection.
If you take default security group

Comment: This is gibberish. Can you try to rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue.
Reason : Since in my Security Group, Inbound traffic to Port 22 was set to MyIP, now since every time I connected to Internet, I got assigned a different IP, while in our Security Group the Inbound Traffic to SSH was expected to come from previous IP only.

Solution : **Edit the Security Group**, and either **make the Inbound Traffic to Port 22 as 'Anywhere'(not recommended) or again click the myIP**(which will give the current IP assigned to you). Problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue. Possible cases are

1. Make sure to open port number-22(ssh) in Inbound rule of Security group
2. Make sure to use correct .ppk file
3. Check Network settings. The VPC in which you have launched an instance, may not have 
   attached to Internet gateway. This happens when you accidentally delete the default 
   Internet- 
   gateway.
   a) Create Internet gateway and attach to the mentioned VPC
   b) In route table->route, add Internet gateway with (0.0.0.0/0)

This should fix the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same Network Error : Connection timeout issue after keep all thing at correct place.

But in my case, internet gateway(igw) is not working so you guys also check default VPC configuration for troubleshooting.

This error is generally occurred because server not responding means source have not clear path to connect to you server even you put SSH 22 port in SG.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add an ssh rule for inbound connections to you ec2 instance.

- Go to ec2 console Security Groups
- Select your Security Groups
- Click edit button on Inbound tab
- Click Add Rule and select SSH for type, Port Range 22, and Source Anywhere or My IP
- Click save rules button

Now connect it's working