# Failed to connect to your instance in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ec2-instance-connect

Hi I am trying to connect my EC2 instance for opening CLI but unfortunately I am getting error:

```
Failed to connect to your instance and my IP address is also not working http://54.179.118.182/
```

Please help me how can I can resolve this.

**Failed to connect to your instance**

```
 We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance network settings are 
   configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, check Task 1 under the Set 
    up EC2 Instance Connect AWS documentation.
```

[Failed to connect to your instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mMnG.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Private AMI, you need to install *ec2-instance-connect*
to your AMI in order to connect with EC2 Instance Connect (SSH connection via AWS).

Comment: actually aws CLI is not working so how can i install ec2 instance connect ?

Comment: Try to connect to your instance via "SSH client", *ssh* or *putty* then install 
`sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect `
(Ubuntu)
`sudo apt-get install ec2-instance-connect`

Comment: but this is also not connecting with putty i see error connection time out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832709/19951115
This will solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following have been properly configured:

- Public subnet route table
- Public subnet route table associations
- Public subnet routes

Also ensure your security group has been configured for ssh communication (port 22)

Answer (score 0):

If you are from windows try removing previously added (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. from know host file located in .ssh folder in users/your username.